# Llenar ArrayList

Tags: java-swing, arraylist

Es posible llenar un ArrayList con los datos que se dan en un JTextArea, soy novato 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes algo como esto:

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea("1,2,3,4,5");
ArrayList<String> listaNumeros = new ArrayList<>();
```

Lo que tu quieres es obtener el contenido de jTextArea, entonces deberás usar el método getText(), separando los números con split().

```
String[] datos = jTextArea.getText().split(",");
```

Y llenar la lista (ArrayList):

```
for(String dato : datos){
    listaNumeros.add(dato);
}
System.out.println(listaNumeros);
```

Con esto tendrías el contenido de JTextArea en un ArrayList.

**Nota:** Es recomendable que cuando programes te ayudes de la documentación oficial. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html